# How can assign all the list value with respect to another length of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-os

**Abstract of my problem:** I am trying to make an excel sheet where the first column contains the sub folders files. And I want to assign the sub folders name in another row concerning the files length, which is contained by the subfolders.

**Let's explain in detail:**
I have 22 sub folders in a specific directory. Each folder contains 9-12 images. For example, Folder no 1, 2, 3, and 4 has accordingly 12, 12, 12, 9, and 11 images. I took all those 22 sub-folders image names in a column. Now, I want to make another row that will contain the folder name with respect to the images name.

```
Image Name  Folder Name
one1.jpg    Folder1
one2.jpg    Folder1
one3.jpg    Folder1
one4.jpg    Folder1
one5.jpg    Folder1
one6.jpg    Folder1
one7.jpg    Folder1
one8.jpg    Folder1
one9.jpg    Folder1
one10.jpg   Folder1
one11.jpg   Folder1
one12.jpg   Folder1
two1.jpg    Folder2
two2.jpg    Folder2
two3.jpg    Folder2
two4.jpg    Folder2
two5.jpg    Folder2
two6.jpg    Folder2
two7.jpg    Folder2
two8.jpg    Folder2
two9.jpg    Folder2
two10.jpg   Folder2
two11.jpg   Folder2
two12.jpg   Folder2
Tree2.jpg   Folder3
.......
```

**I get so close but not to the end:**

```
path1 = os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Images')

subDirectory = list(os.walk(path1))
sd = subDirectory[0][1]
lengthOFsd = len(sd)
lengthOFsd = (lengthOFsd+1)



# import xlsxwriter module
# !pip install xlsxwriter

import xlsxwriter

path2 = os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/excle')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data_path_reader.xlsx')

# By default worksheet names in the spreadsheet will be
# Sheet1, Sheet2 etc., but we can also specify a name.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("First _Sheet")

# Use the worksheet object to write
# data via the write() method.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Image Name')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Folder Name')
current_directory = os.listdir(path1)
subDirectory = list(os.walk(path1))

row = 1
row2 =1
col = 0
col2 = 0

# For 1st column images name
for j in range(1,lengthOFsd):
  subd1 = list(subDirectory[j][2])
  for imgname in subd1:
    worksheet.write(row, col, imgname)
    row += 1 

# For 2nd column Folders name
lenoffoldImg = len(subDirectory[1][2])
for flodername in range(0,lenoffoldImg):
  worksheet.write_column(row2, col2 + 1, sd)
  row2 += 1

workbook.close()
```

If you want to check the full code [click here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qIJxzOSMIPNp1ibydJ_MU6BRof0C_ku-?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Here I have used the library `openpyxl`, since I am not used to working with `xlsxwriter`. Nonetheless, the logic is the same, and I am positive you can adapt it to your needs.

Here is the solution:

```
from os import walk, getcwd
from os.path import basename
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active


sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = "Image Name"
sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Folder Name" 


# If you would like to skip the files in the root file remove this variable and its logic. 
skip_root_files = True

# The row in which the file and folder's name will be printed.
row_number = 2

for foldername, _, filenames in walk(getcwd()):
    # Skip files from root directory logic:
    if skip_root_files:
        skip_root_files = False
        continue

    for filename in filenames: 
        sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=1).value = filename
        sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=2).value = basename(foldername)

        row_number += 1

wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

As explained in the comments, if you don't want to crawl the root directory just create a logic to pass the first loop cycle, (i.e the root). I've done it with booleans.

The variable `row_number` starts by 2 because it leaves the first row to the titles `Image Name` and `Folder Name`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found the solution. Your code also works fine. But you initiate 'skip_root_files = true' but it will 'skip_root_files = True' and 'skip_root_files = False'. BTW it a very silly I think. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Both booleans are now capitalized. Thanks for noticing the mistake. Hope the solution was helpful.

Comment: By the way, why do you have two couples of variables "row(1), row2" and "col(1), col2" instead of only a unique `row` variable? You are essentially always working in the same row when looping through the for, and the columns are always going to be 1 and 2 (or 0 and 1, if not `openpyxl`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the **solution**. There is little change in the loop, which is given in below:

> **Solution**

```
for j in range(0,lengthOFsd):
  subd1 = list(subDirectory[j][2])
  foldername = os.path.basename(subDirectory[j][0])              
  for imgname in subd1:
    worksheet.write(row1, col1, imgname)
    worksheet.write(row2, col2 + 1, foldername)
    row1 += 1
    row2 += 1
```

> Note:- This change for the first loop and remove the second loop